# Why Do I get an ImportError when building a .exe with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, ipython, scikit-learn, pyinstaller, py2app

I just created a small GUI program that compiles and works fine in IPython, but when I try to export it to a `.exe` using pyinstaller it gives me an import error. I'm sure it's `sklearn` because when I comment out the `sklearn` imports my file open fine when I build it.

```
C:\Users\Chris\Anaconda>C:/Users/Chris/Anaconda/dist/Room_Test.exe
WARNING: file already exists but should not:                            C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI100402\Include\pyconfig.h
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Chris\Anaconda\Lib\site-    packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Anaconda\build\Room_Test\out00-    PYZ.pyz\sklearn.neighbors", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Anaconda\Lib\site-    packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 409, in load_module
    module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, self._c_ext_tuple)
  File "dist_metrics.pxd", line 48, in init sklearn.neighbors.ball_tree     (sklearn\neighbors\ball_tree.c:35726)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Anaconda\Lib\site-    packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 409, in load_module
    module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, self._c_ext_tuple)
  File "dist_metrics.pyx", line 52, in init sklearn.neighbors.dist_metrics     (sklearn\neighbors\dist_metrics.c:25494)
ImportError: No module named typedefs
```

Comment: This is not python, rather Pyrex C extension. I suppose pyinstaller can't deal with that automatically.

Answer (score 14):

You can still use pyinstaller by adding the following to your command:

```
--hidden-import sklearn.neighbors.typedefs
```

or by adding the following to your `.spec` file:

```
hiddenimports=['cython', 'sklearn', 'sklearn.neighbors.typedefs']
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem and when I included `--hidden-import sklearn.neighbors.typedefs` I got the following error: `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Comment: @PankajJoshi - you can try setting the recursion limit in the spec file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977929/pyinstaller-creating-exe-runtimeerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-while-ca

Answer (score 9):

its better to use spec file to import another hidden libraries maybe cause the problem. I list all Sklearn libraries and add to spec file as a hiddenimports like this:

```
  # -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['MyPythonApplication.py'],
             pathex=['..\\ApplicationFolder'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['cython', 'sklearn', 'sklearn.ensemble', 'sklearn.neighbors.typedefs', 'sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree', 'sklearn.tree._utils'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='ExeFileName',             
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          console=False )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='ApplicationName')
```

Comment: This worked great for me! Just had to add 'sklearn.pipeline' in my case also.

Answer (score 3):

Solved it myself! Ended up using py2exe. Much easier to import modules even though bundling to one .exe is not yet supported on x64 systems. But worked for my purposes. Just added the following line to the "includes":

```
sklearn.neighbors.typedefs
```

Answer (score 1):

Find this dir "E:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks".
Add a file "hook-pandas.py",wrie this content to this file:

```
"""
Hook for pandas. 
Suport for pyinstaller error : No module named ‘pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas
"""
hiddenimports=[
    #all your previous hidden imports
    'pandas', 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas',
    'sklearn.neighbors.typedefs'
]
```

Then use this command:

```
pyinstaller -F myfile.py --hidden-import sklearn.neighbors.typedefs
```

Then it will be OK!