# pyinstaller creating EXE RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, recursion, scipy, exe, pyinstaller

I am running WinPython 3.4.4.3 with pyinstaller 3.2 (obtained via pip install pyinstaller).

Now I've got some really simple Qt4 code that I want to convert to EXE and I've run into problem that I cannot solve.

**The Code:**

```
import sys
import math
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore 
import SMui
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

class SomeCalculation(QtGui.QMainWindow, SMui.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Some Calculation')
        self.calculate.clicked.connect(self.some_math)

    def some_math(self):
        a_diameter=self.a_diameter.value()
        b_diameter=self.b_diameter.value()
        complement=self.complement.value()
        angle=self.angle.value()
        preload=self.preload.value()

### ONLY MATH HAPPENS HERE also defining X and Y ####

        interpolator = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(X, Y)

### MORE MATH HAPPENS HERE ####

        self.axial.setText(str(axial))
        self.radial.setText(str(radial))

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window=SomeCalculation()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

I try to run `pyinstaller file_name.py` and I'm getting:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Now if there's a few things that I have found out that also affect the issue:

1) If I comment out this line: `from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline`

2) Creating EXE file from another different script that uses Scipy.Interpolate (RBS, but still) - works like a charm.

3) If I try to convert it to EXE using WinPython 3.5.1.1 + pyinstaller obtained the same way, and it's the same 3.2 version of it - it generates my exe file no problems.

I want to understand what's causing the error in the original case and I cannot find any answer on google unfortunately, most of the fixes I could find were related with matplotlib and not interpolation though.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 85):

This worked for me

1. Run pyinstaller and stop it to generate the spec file :

   ```
   pyinstaller filename.py
   ```

   A file with `.spec` as extension should be generated
2. Now add the following lines to the beginning of the spec file :

   ```
   import sys
   sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
   ```
3. Now run the spec file using :

   ```
   pyinstaller filename.spec
   ```

Comment: Wondering why creators of pyinstaller do not give recursionlimit as a commnad-line option. Or at lease mention the problem in the FAQ somewhere.

Comment: Thank you. Nothing on the internet worked for me except this!

Comment: For me, it worked, but couldn't get any use of the EXE file. It runs but it will close afterward.

Comment: @Pedram open a terminal and run it from there

Comment: I am getting that error all of a sudden. And I always used a specfile.

Answer (score 34):

Mustafa did guide me to the right direction, you have to increase the recursion limit. But the code has to be put to the beginning of the spec file and not in your python code:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
```

Create the spec file with `pyi-makespec` first, edit it and then build by passing the spec file to the `pyinstaller` command. See the pyinstaller manual for more information about [using spec files](http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html).

Please make sure to use pyinstaller 3.2.0, with 3.2.1 you will get `ImportError: cannot import name 'is_module_satisfies'` (see the [issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2384) on GitHub)

Answer (score 8):

Even until March 2020, this issue has not been solved yet. As per some people's explanation, I increased setrecursionlimit in .spec file and tried to build it, but it did not work.

Through googling, I found out that this issue is caused by conflict of latest version of openpyxl and pyinstaller.   Older version of openpyxl, such as 2.3.5 version, does not cause this issue.

As such, solution for this issue is as follows.

```
pip uninstall openpyxl
pip install openpyxl==2.3.5
```

Answer (score 6):

i'd try to increase recursion depth limit. Insert at the beginning of your file:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
```

Comment: Did that. Doesn't help.

Comment: This seems to help for me, any idea why? Do you have a pointer?

Comment: When I try to run a script from outside the package containing module, it errors out but if I call the script within the package it succeeds. Any idea ?

Comment: This must be included at the top of the `.spec` file, not the python file.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes even the limit 5000 is not enough. It helped me to set limit to 20000. (in file 'filename.spec')

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(20000)
```

Answer (score 1):

make new environment with pipenv and install just the requirements package.
(unused package which you have on your environment will cause the increase of the size of .exe file and make this error happen )
i try with python 3.8 and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can make changes to the recursion limit in the following manner:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I tried most of the things suggested here. But, I could not solve the issue on my laptop. What worked for me is summarized below:

1. Open Anaconda prompt.
2. Activate your environment using conda activate my_env.
3. Navigate to your project folder from the Anaconda command prompt using cd your_folder_directory.
4. Run pyinstaller --onefile my_python_file.py

This should not create any recursion error.
This will create a dist folder in your project directory. Your executable will present in this folder.

Answer (score 0):

install pyinstaller last developer version:

```
pip uninstall pyinstaller
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your pyinstaller to 5.6.2

First uninstall your current pyinstaller

`pip uninstall pyinstaller`

Install pyinstaller 5.6.2 version

`pip install pyinstaller==5.6.2`

This worked for me.
Latest versions kept giving me the 'maximum recursion depth exceeded error' the moment i tried running my .exe