# pandas_datareader & pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, packaging, pandas-datareader

Has any of you encounter the below issue with pyinstaller?  I have a code that uses pandas_datareader and it seems to be the reason why pyinstaller returns **RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded**

here's a simple code that I used to test and confirm that pdr is the only lib that breaks in pyinstaller

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr

print(pdr.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start="2020-04-06", end="2020-04-06"))
```

I'm using

- python 3.7.4
- Pyinstaller 3.6
- pandas_datareader 0.8.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51254042/13014070) from Aviral

it seems that the issue was the limit number of recursion.  Once I changed it to 5000 it went through