# Make exe file of python pypylon project using pyinstaller spec file

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, pylons

In my python project, I used Basler GigE Vision ethernet cameras, because of the pylon doesn't support python then I used [pypylon.pylon wrapper](https://github.com/StudentCV/PyPylon) to open it in python. This is my class to open the camera, but after making executable file I get errors when opening it. [I used spec file to work with pyinstaller.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48264244/1364213)I get this below errors:

```
import pypylon.pylon as py
import numpy as np


class PylonVideoReader:

def __init__(self, deviceName=None):
    self.deviceName = deviceName
    tlfactory = py.TlFactory.GetInstance()
    if not self.deviceName is None:
        deviceInfoList = tlfactory.EnumerateDevices()
        deviceIndex = None
        for i in range(len(deviceInfoList)):
            if self.deviceName == deviceInfoList[i].GetUserDefinedName():
                deviceIndex = i
                break

        if deviceIndex is None:
            print("Device: {} not found please ensure that it is "
                  "connected".format(self.deviceName))
            exit()
        else:
            # Create new camera
            self.camera = py.InstantCamera(tlfactory.CreateDevice(
                deviceInfoList[deviceIndex]))
    else:
        # Create new camera
        self.camera = py.InstantCamera(tlfactory.CreateFirstDevice())

    # Open camera
    self.camera.Open()
    # Set max number of frame buffers
    self.camera.MaxNumBuffer = 50
    # Initialize the  image format converter
    self.formatConverter = py.ImageFormatConverter()
    # Set output pixel format to BGR8 for opencv
    self.formatConverter.OutputPixelFormat = py.PixelType_BGR8packed

    # Start grabbing process
    self.camera.StartGrabbing(py.GrabStrategy_LatestImageOnly)
    # Grab a first image to get its size
    grabResult = self.camera.RetrieveResult(10000)
    # Stop grabbing process
    # self.camera.StopGrabbing()

    # Get dimensions of image
    self.frameWidth = grabResult.GetWidth()
    self.frameHeight = grabResult.GetHeight()

def get(self, code):
    if code == 3:
        return self.frameWidth
    elif code == 4:
        return self.frameHeight
    else:
        print("{} is not a known property code".format(code))

def read(self):
    # try:

    # Start grabing process
    # self.camera.StartGrabbing(py.GrabStrategy_LatestImageOnly)
    # Grab an image
    grabResult = self.camera.RetrieveResult(10000)
    # Stop grabing process
    # self.camera.StopGrabbing()
    # Get dimensions of image
    self.frameWidth = grabResult.GetWidth()
    self.frameHeight = grabResult.GetHeight()

    if grabResult.GrabSucceeded():
        # Convert Grab result from YUV422 to BGR8
        pylonImage = self.formatConverter.Convert(grabResult)
        # Convert pylon image to opencv image
        # image = np.frombuffer(bytearray(pylonImage.GetBuffer()), np.uint8)
        image = np.asarray(bytearray(pylonImage.GetBuffer()), np.uint8)
        image = image.reshape(self.frameHeight, self.frameWidth, 3)

        return (True, image)
    # except :
    return (False, None)

def release(self):
    self.camera.StopGrabbing()
    self.camera.Close()
```

main code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":    
    cap = PylonVideoReader("Admin1")
    cv2.namedWindow("Test1", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    while True:
        ret, image = cap.read()                
        if ret:
            cv2.imshow("Test1", image)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) % 256 == ord('q'):
            break
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "site-packages\pypylon\pylon.py", line 42, in swig_import_helper
>   File "importlib__init__.py", line 126, in import_module   File
>   "", line 994, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 971, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>   **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pypylon._pylon'**
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "MainGuiLogic.py", line 18,
>   in    File
>   "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
>   line 631, in exec_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)   File "PylonVideoReader.py", line 1, in    File
>   "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
>   line 631, in exec_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)   File "site-packages\pypylon\pylon.py", line 45, in    File
>   "site-packages\pypylon\pylon.py", line 44, in swig_import_helper
>   File "importlib__init__.py", line 126, in import_module   File
>   "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
>   line 714, in load_module
>       module = loader.load_module(fullname) ModuleNotFoundError: **No module named 'pypylon._genicam'** [4300] Failed to execute script
>   MainGuiLogic [4300] LOADER: OK. [4300] LOADER: Cleaning up Python
>   interpreter.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: Yes, I found a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making the executable files with pyinstaller ([How to make executable file with pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48264244/1364213)) you should find the pypylon folder from your virtual environment which used in the project and copy the pypylon folder beside the exe file.

Comment: This solution didn't work when building a single file, only when building to a folder.

Comment: In the given sample in the above link, I didn't use a single EXE file

Comment: My previous comment was for others who may find this question (like I did) and wonder why the marked solution is not working for them. My solution worked for single EXE; others may find that useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around this issue by doing the following, some steps may not be necessary, but so far, this has worked in my case. I found [this github issue](https://github.com/basler/pypylon/issues/36) helpful and put me on the right track.

First, excessive importing in my script:

```
import pypylon
import pathlib
from pypylon import pylon
from pypylon import genicam
from pypylon import _genicam
from pypylon import _pylon
```

I'd advise against the way you imported pypylon in your example, refering to a package simply as "py" will be confusing for other developers.

Next, I modified my spec file's `binaries`, `pathex`, and `hiddenimports`.  I added all of the pylon dll and pyd files to `binaries`, appended the pypylon directory to `pathex`, and added all of the possibilities to `hiddenimports`:

```
import pypylon
pypylon_dir = pathlib.Path(pypylon.__file__).parent
pypylon_dlls = [(str(dll), '.') for dll in pypylon_dir.glob('*.dll')]
pypylon_pyds = [(str(dll), '.') for dll in pypylon_dir.glob('*.pyd')]

_binaries = list()
_binaries.extend(pypylon_dlls)
_binaries.extend(pypylon_pyds)

_pathex = list()
_pathex.append(str(pypylon_dir))

_hiddenimports = list()
_hiddenimports.extend(['pypylon', 'pypylon.pylon', 'pypylon.genicam', 'pypylon._pylon', 'pypylon._genicam'])

a = Analysis(...
             pathex=_pathex,
             binaries=_binaries,
             ...
             hiddenimports=_hiddenimports,
```

I'm not sure all of that is strictly necessary, but it's working for me with Python 3.4, PyInstaller 3.3, and pypylon 1.3.1.

Good luck!